# C++ Infix to postfix converter - Know where the error is but won't go into if statement?

Tags: c++

So I basically have the infix to postfix converter and evaluator working, however, it breaks when the input in the text files have more than one set of parentheses such as (2+4)*(3+4) and I know where it's breaking. However, I cannot seem to find a way around this. I've put a comment break where it's failing.

I have been trying stuff all night and for whatever reason, it just will not enter that if( ) statement.

I've put my code below:

Header:

```
    #ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////Includes/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
template <typename Object>
class Stack
{
private:
    class stackListNode
        {
        public:
            Object data;
            stackListNode *next;
        private:
            //Nothing to declare-->placeholder since class 
            //sets data members to private initially
        };

    stackListNode *top;

public:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Constructor Function//////////////////////////
    Stack() {top = NULL;}

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Rest of functions defined inline for simplicity

        void push(char token)   // Push token onto the stack and create new node for top of stack
            {
                stackListNode *newNode = new stackListNode;
                newNode->data = token;
                newNode->next = top;
                top = newNode;
            }

        char pop()
            {
                if(empty())
                {
                    cout << "Stack is empty!\n" << endl;
                    return NULL;                
                }

                stackListNode *temp = top;
                top = temp->next;
                return temp->data;
            }

        char peek()
            {
                if(empty())
                {
                    cout << "Stack is empty!\n" << endl;
                    //exit(1);
                    return NULL;                
                }
                return top->data;
            }

        int empty()
            {
                return top == NULL;
            }


        int isempty()
        {
            int i = 1;
            if(empty())
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

Driver:

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////Includes/////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
using namespace std;

int precendence(char stack_beginning); //overloaded for character sitting at the front of the stack
void InFixToPostfix(ifstream& in_file);
//double EvaluatePostfix(double first_operand, double second_operand, char*myArray);

int main()
{
////VARS/////////////////////////////////////////////

    string absolutePath;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please type in the name of the file you would to open \n";
    cin >> absolutePath;

    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(absolutePath.c_str());
    if(!in_file)
    {
        cout << "failed to open input file\n" ;
        return 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        InFixToPostfix(in_file); //kicks off program
    }

}

void InFixToPostfix(ifstream& in_file)
{
    string infix;
    int right_parentheses = 0;
    int left_parentheses = 0;

    while(getline(in_file, infix))
    {
        char myArray[infix.length()];
        strcpy(myArray, infix.c_str());
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Read in string " << myArray << endl;


////////Declares a STRING Stack////////////////////////////////
        Stack<char> stack_string;
////////Declares an Int Stack/////////////////////////////////
        Stack<int> stack_int;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int j = 0;
        int m = 0;
        char *postfix = new char[infix.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++)
        {
            int number = myArray[i]-'0';
            if(number > 0)
            {
                postfix[j] = myArray[i];
                j++;
                cout << "array value: " << myArray[i]<<endl;
                //outputs the number b/c it is an operand
            }
            else if(myArray[i] == '('){
                stack_string.push(myArray[i]);
                m++;
            }
            else if(myArray[i] == ')')
            {
                while(stack_string.peek() != '(')
                {
                    cout << "first character on the stack: "<< stack_string.peek() << endl;
                    postfix[j] = stack_string.peek();
                    j++;
                    cout << "the postfix is " << postfix[j] << " ";
                    stack_string.pop();
                    m--;
                    //cout << "stack is popping: " << stack_string.pop() << endl; //pops to the peek
                }
            cout << "the stack just popped: " << stack_string.pop() << endl; // if there is a ), pops to the peek
            m--;
            }
            else if(myArray[i] == '+' || myArray[i] == '-' || myArray[i] == '/' || myArray[i] == '*')
            {

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////THIS IS WHERE IT IS BREAKING -- WILL NOT GO INTO THIS IF() STATEMENT//
                if(!stack_string.isempty())
                {
                        cout << "ERROR IS HERE";
                        char stack_beginning = stack_string.peek();
                        int stack_top = precendence(stack_beginning);
                        int operatorHierarchy = precendence(myArray[i]);
                        while(operatorHierarchy >= stack_top)
                        {
                            cout << "the stack just popped again: " << stack_string.pop() << endl;
                            m--;
                            cout << postfix[j] << " ";
                            postfix[j] = myArray[i];
                            j++;
                            stack_top = precendence(stack_beginning);
                            operatorHierarchy = precendence(myArray[i]);
                        }
                    }
            stack_string.push(myArray[i]);
           // cout <<"here"<< myArray[i]<< endl;
            }
        }
        while(!stack_string.empty())
        {
           //char c = (char)stack_string.pop();
           postfix[j] = stack_string.pop();
           j++;
        }

//////////Evaluate Section/////////////////////////////
        //cout << postfix <<endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int w = 0; w <= j; w++){
            cout<< postfix[w] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i <= j; i++)
        {
            //cout<<myArray[i]<<endl;

            /////////////////////////////////
            ////////////////////////////////
            int number = postfix[i] - '0';
            cout << "postfix in loop is " << postfix[i] <<endl;
            if(number > 0) //this is a number
            {
                stack_int.push(number);
                cout << "the first character on the stack is: " <<  stack_int.peek() << endl;
            }
            else if(postfix[i] == '*' || postfix[i] == '+' || postfix[i] == '-' || postfix[i] == '/')
            {
                int first_operand;
                first_operand = stack_int.peek(); //fetches first operand on the stack_int
                cout << "the stack just popped once again: " << stack_int.pop() << endl;
                //////////////////
                int second_operand;
                second_operand = stack_int.peek();
                cout << "the stack just popped once again: " << stack_int.pop() << endl;
                //////////////////
                if(postfix[i] == '*')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand * first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '/')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand / first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '+')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand + first_operand);
                }
                else if(postfix[i] == '-')
                {
                    stack_int.push(second_operand - first_operand);
                }
            }
        }
    cout <<"result is: " << (int)stack_int.pop() << endl;
    }
}

int precendence(char stack_beginning)
{
    int precendence;
    if(stack_beginning == '(')
    {
        precendence = 3;
        return precendence;
    }
    else if(stack_beginning == '*' || stack_beginning == '/')
    {
        precendence = 2;
        return precendence;
    }
    //by making it 2, the precendence is dubbed less than +/-
    else if(stack_beginning == '+' || stack_beginning == '-')
    {
        precendence = 1;
        return precendence;
    }
}    //by making it 1, the precendence is dubbed greater than */"/"
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to implement your own `Stack` when we have STL? :)

Comment: You really should use a *debugger* instead of relying on StackOverflow. A debugger is a lot faster to use.

Comment: As I stated in a reply to your earlier post, your `empty` function needs to return `bool` not `int`.  The result of `operator==` is `bool`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `isempty()` method, you're not returning a value if the stack ISN'T empty.

```
....

int isempty()
{
    int i = 1;
    if(empty())
    {
        return i;
    }
}

....
```

In the above, you're missing a return statement if `empty()` returns `false`. This will result in undefined behaviour. On the face of it, this undefined behaviour looks like it results in a miscellaneous non-zero integer being returned.

I would just use the `empty()` method, and get rid of the `isempty()` method altogether.